# How to implement a full screen notification like whatsapp call in react native android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, notifications, onesignal

I want to implement a notification service in which I am able to display a full screen notification even on the lock screen like a whatsapp call in react native android and one signal. I didn't find any stable solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package to achieve the full screen notification:

https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/android/behaviour#full-screen

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: Follow this link.

https://github.com/invertase/notifee/issues/501#issuecomment-1246700681